# Kinect 2 skinning a model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I am looking at using the Kinect version 2 for PC to control an avatar, i.e. apply a skin to the body basics example provided by Microsoft.

The avatar isn't to be used in a game or anything at this point. I simply plan to be able to control the avatar using the Kinect 2 and record to .avi. I have already implemented a demo where I can record the Kinect footage of the skeleton directly to .avi.

After searching I found that it was possible to control an avatar with the original Kinect using XNA game studio. As XNA game studio seems a bit out dated now and I'm unsure if it would be compatible with version 2, would there be an alternative approach? Does anybody know of a project where someone has done this already? Or can anyone suggest a good approach to take to do this?

I have also seen some articles referring to a plugin that lets you use Unity with Kinect 2 but from what I can see I don't believe this is publicly available?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I have been able to find the plugin for Unity, it is quite well hidden. So I will attempt to get something working in Unity, unless any one can offer a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the unity plug in works great and its the best out there. the creator its call rumen, he will help you if you need it help but ofcourse you have to pay the plugin 1st. its worth it, it makes kinect way simpler.